# Using realloc() to remove data from the beginning of an allocated segment?

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

Say I have a dynamically allocated array:

```
int * arr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * oldSize);
for(int i = 0; i < oldSize; i++){
    arr[i] = i;
}
```

and I wanted to shrink that memory segment to a size `newSize` so that `arr` only consists of:

`{oldSize - newSize, ... oldSize - 1}`

Is it possible to do this without going through every single element in the array (aside from the first `n` elements, where `n` is `oldSize - newSize`) and shifting them back `n` positions before calling `arr = realloc(arr, sizeof(int) * newSize)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to move the elements you want to keep to the start of the list.  Fortunately, there's a function for this, `memmove`:

```
memmove(arr, arr + (oldsize-newsize), newsize * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: Or better: `memmove(arr, arr + (oldsize-newsize), newsize * sizeof(*arr));`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard function `memmove` to move the elements starting from the expression `oldSize - newSize` to the beginning of the array and then call the function `realloc`.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    size_t oldSize = 10;
    size_t newSize = 6;
    
    int * arr = malloc( sizeof(int) * oldSize );
    
    for ( int i = 0; ( size_t )i < oldSize; i++ )
    {
        arr[i] = i;
    }
    
    for ( int i = 0; ( size_t )i < oldSize; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", arr[i] );
    }
        
    putchar( '\n' );

    memmove( arr, arr + ( oldSize - newSize ), newSize * sizeof( int ) );
    
    int *tmp = realloc( arr, newSize * sizeof( int ) );
    
    if ( tmp != NULL )
    {
        arr = tmp;
        
        for ( int i = 0; ( size_t )i < newSize; i++ )
        {
            printf( "%d ", arr[i] );
        }
        
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
    
    free( arr );
    
    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
4 5 6 7 8 9
```